# Combining duplicate results

Tags: sql, join

I wish to run a query that will return cost of services from a table of customer requests. There are multiple requests from the same customer in the requests table.

I have the query:

> ```
> SELECT REQUESTS.CUST, PRICE.COST
> FROM REQUESTS
> JOIN PRICE ON REQUESTS.SERV = PRICE.SERV
> ORDER BY REQUESTS.CUST ASC
> ```

This returns cost of services as follows:

> ```
> CUST|Cost
> 1001|10
> 1002|5
> 1002|4
> ```

I need this to return

> ```
> Cust|Cost
> 1001|10
> 1002|9
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT REQUESTS.CUST, SUM(PRICE.COST)
FROM REQUESTS
JOIN PRICE ON REQUESTS.SERV = PRICE.SERV
GROUP BY REQUESTS.CUST
ORDER BY REQUESTS.CUST ASC
```

Comment: I have tried that, it returns #1054 - Unknown column 'REQUEST.CUST' in 'group statement'

Comment: I think you missed the S of REQUESTS

Comment: WOW, tried so many times, and made the exact same error every time. Thank you for pointing that out, was driving me crazy!!!

Comment: No problem. Please mark answer as answered if all okay to you.

Comment: Will do, dont suppose I could bother you for a count for the customers individual orders could I?

Comment: Is that a separate table? Can you show the data? Maybe you need a new question for that. As a tip: Use the count statement.

Comment: thank you for all of your assistance. Solved my second question with

Comment: SELECT REQUESTS.CUST, SUM( PRICE.COST ) AS TOTAL, COUNT(*) AS     ORDERS
    FROM REQUESTS
    JOIN PRICE ON REQUESTS.SERV = PRICE.SERV
    GROUP BY REQUESTS.CUST
    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC, ORDERS DESC

Comment: now i'm getting really adventurist and wondering how i can display locational data from another table for the results of this table. eg cust|totals|orders|(LATLONG from 3rd table). Would be nice but I may be getting carried away with things! Starting to think I will never be content. Thank you for all your assistance

Comment: Enjoy your adventures. Indeed they will never end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your customers:

```
SELECT REQUESTS.CUST, sum(PRICE.COST)
FROM REQUESTS
JOIN PRICE ON REQUESTS.SERV = PRICE.SERV
GROUP BY REQUESTS.CUST
ORDER BY REQUESTS.CUST ASC
```

Comment: I have tried that, it returns #1054 - Unknown column 'REQUEST.CUST' in 'group statement'